# Calculating the mode in a multimodal list in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the mode (most frequent value) of a list of values in Python.  I came up with a solution, which gave out the wrong answer anyway, but I then realised that my data may be mutlimodal;

```
ie 1,1,2,3,4,4 mode = 1 & 4
```

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
def mode(valueList):
  frequencies = {}
  for value in valueList:
    if value in frequencies:
      frequencies[value] += 1
    else:
      frequencies[value] = 1
  mode = max(frequencies.itervalues())
  return mode
```

I think the problem here is that I'm outputting the value rather than the pointer of the maximum value.  Anyway can anyone suggest a better way of doing this that could work where there is more than one mode?  Or failing that how I can fix what I've got so far and identify a single mode?

As you can probably tell I'm very new to python, thanks for the help.

edit: should have mentioned I'm in Python 2.4

Comment: You should really upgrade to latest supported version of Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the first problem is that yes, you're returning the value in `frequences` rather than the key. That means you get the *count* of the mode, not the mode itself. Normally, to get the mode, you'd use the `key` keyword argument to max, like so:

```
>>> max(frequencies, key=counts.get())
```

But in 2.4 that doesn't exist! Here's an approach that I believe will work in 2.4:

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [random.randrange(0, 5) for _ in range(50)]
>>> frequencies = {}
>>> for i in l:
...     frequencies[i] = frequencies.get(i, 0) + 1
... 
>>> frequencies
{0: 11, 1: 13, 2: 8, 3: 8, 4: 10}
>>> mode = max((v, k) for k, v in frequencies.iteritems())[1]
>>> mode
1
>>> max_freq = max(frequencies.itervalues())
>>> modes = [k for k, v in frequencies.iteritems() if v == max_freq]
>>> modes
[1]
```

I prefer the decorate-sort-undecorate idiom to the `cmp` keyword. I think it's more readable. Could be that's just me.

Comment: Excellent thanks, also I should have mentioned that I'm in 2.4.  I've updated the post.

Comment: @Captastic, argh. No `defaultdict`, no `Counter`, and no `key` argument to `max`. Phew. Have to do this the hard way... just a sec.

Comment: In Py2.4, you would use the `cmp` argument to `max` instead of `key` (which didn't exist yet); so, `mode = max(frequencies, cmp=lambda i,j: cmp(counts[i], counts[j]))`.

Comment: @senderle that's the one!  It works wonderfully.  Thank you very much.  Now to learn how the hell it works :)

Answer (score 5):

In Python >=2.7, use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for frequency tables.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile

data = [1,1,2,3,4,4]
freq = Counter(data)
mostfreq = freq.most_common()
modes = list(takewhile(lambda x_f: x_f[1] == mostfreq[0][1], mostfreq))
```

Note the use of an anonymous function (`lambda`) that checks whether a pair `(_, f)` has the same frequency as the most frequent element.

Comment: @Captastic: then you should really upgrade. Python 2.4 is from 2004; even Python 2.5 no longer receives security patches.

Comment: I'll be darned if I can get that last "takewhile" line to work without a SyntaxError on my version 3.2.3, but I'm a newbie. Thoughts?

Comment: @MatthewCornell: tuple unpacking in function definitions (including lambdas) was removed in 3.2, or maybe even earlier. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Note that starting in `Python 3.8`, the standard library includes the [`statistics.multimode`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html?highlight=mode#statistics.multimode) function to return a list of the most frequently occurring values in the order they were first encountered:

```
from statistics import multimode

multimode([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4])
# [1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use counter for the top value while iterating, something like this:

```
def mode(valueList):
  frequencies = {}
  mx = None
  for value in valueList:
    if value in frequencies:
      frequencies[value] += 1
    else:
      frequencies[value] = 1
    if not mx or frequencies[value] > mx[1]:
      mx = (value, frequencies[value])

  mode = mx[0]
  return mode
```

another approach for multiple modes, using nlargest, which can give you the N largest values of a dictionary:

```
from heapq import nlargest
import operator

def mode(valueList, nmodes):
  frequencies = {}

  for value in valueList:
    frequencies[value] = frequencies.get(value, 0) + 1

  return [x[0] for x in nlargest(nmodes,frequencies.iteritems(),operator.itemgetter(1))]
```

Comment: That'd do it, thanks.  Though not sure how I'd convert it to work with more than one mode.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've gone with senderles approach but I'll have to have a play with yours if only for the learning experience.